# Constraint Satisfaction Problem formulation

Tags: python, search, constraints, backtracking, constraint-programming

I am given the following requirements which need to be formulated into a CSP problem by defining a set of variables, and a set of constraints over those variables. However I'm having trouble formulating the constraints and variables for my problem.

**Some info:**
The solution to the problem is a list of assignments: `[Var, A1, A2, A3]`
where `Var` is the variable and `A1`, `A2`, `A3` is an ordered sequence of valid assignments.

**Requirements:**

- Each variable is assigned a value in `problem.valid_assignments()`
- Each variable's first assignment is in `problem.first_assignments()`
- Each variable's assignment sequence is in `problem.valid_pairs()` (Some assignments can't follow others)
- Given an integer `K`, there can be no more than `K` continuous assignments where at least one is not in problem.k_assignment()
- Every value in the given assignments list: `problem.assignment` must be used.

**Available Constraints:**

- `NValues` constraint: Given a list of `required_values`, an upper bound and lower bound, makes sure that the number of variables whose value is in `required_values` is between the bounds.
- `AllDifferent` constraint: Given a set of variables, enforces their inequality. That is no two variables in the set are equal.
- `NotEqual` constraints: Given `Var1`, `Var2`, enforces: `Var1` != `Var2`

**So Far:**

- A Variable for each `Var` whose domain is `problem.valid_assignments()`
- A Variable for each `Var` whose domain is `problem.first_assignments()`
- A `NValues` constraint for each `Var` whose scope is `[Var]`, required values `problem.valid_assignments(Var)`, lower bound `0`, upper bound `len(domain)`.

**Additional info:**

- The solution is a "list of assignments" as in for each `Var` we return `[Var, A1, A2, A3]` where `Var` is the variable assigned and `A1` through `A3` are valid assignments that fulfil the given constraints. The exact format doesn't matter as I'm only looking for a conceptual solution. Additionally `A1, A2, A3` (aka all assignments for a `Var`) must obviously be in the domain of that variable. (Domains can overlap between variables).
- `valid_pairs()` returns a list of tuples `[(A1, A2), (A2,A3)]`. The constraint is such that the returned solution list (as detailed above) must have consecutive assignments that form valid pairs that are given by this function. For example if the solution is `[Var, A1, A2, A4, A3]` and the valid pairs are `[(A1, A2), (A2,A3)]` then the solution is incorrect as `(A2, A4) (A4, A3)` is not in the list (`(A1, A2)` however is a valid pair).
- Essentially we're looking for arc-consistency.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "list of assignments", is it the same as the "domain"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem#Formal_definition

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand what "valid_pairs()" is. Can you give one positive and one negative example?

Comment: Please seed my latest edit for clarifications. @MichaelVeksler

Comment: If for each variable I take a random value, one from its list of valid assignments, will this collection (of variables and their values) satisfy all the constraints?

Comment: No. It will satisfy only the basic constraint that the variable is assigned to valid (ie possible) assignments. However it is not guaranteed that there order will satisfy the other constraints (such as each pair being valid). @MichaelVeksler

Comment: So basically, your only requirement is arc-consistency?

Comment: Yeah if I understood arc-consistency properly. @MichaelVeksler

Comment: `v= ["Var", "A1", "A2", "A3"]` than `print [ (v[i],v[i+1])for i in range(1,len(v)-1)]` **v** List of returned results(if used `python3.X` create an `drange`  function)

Comment: please show what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can use an `NValues` constraint whose scope is all variables, and domain is each possible assignment (For each assignment create a constraint). This ensures that all values are assigned when set to have an upper and lower bound of 1.
- We can use use `Neq` constraint with a bit of modification to ensure the correct sequencing by feeding it tuples of valid assignments.
- We can again use `NValues` constraint to ensure the `k_assignment` requirement by passing a lower bound of 1, and upper bound of `K` with domain `K_assignments`.
- In the same way we can use `NValues` constraint with domain `problem.first_assignments()` for the first assignment. And another with domain `problem.valid_assignments()` to fill in the blanks.